# Can a Jenkins Maven build be executed on separate servers?

Tags: maven, build, jenkins

Specifically, have the Jenkins instance running on a Linux server execute a Maven build on a Windows server

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you can have a master-slave relation with another box: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

If you only want launch a maven build there without setting up a slave, you can install the [ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin), configure ssh access on the Windows box, and then remotely execute the maven build